# can't load scores from leaderboard

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-games, leaderboard

i'm setting up a leaderboard system in my unity game, using the google play games services plugin.

i want to load score in order to integrate them in my custom LeaderbordUI, 
I followed the documentation and used the ILeaderboard.LoadScores but it's not working.

when i check the logcat i get this :

**02-04 11:03:56.580: W/Unity(18969): !!! [Play Games Plugin DLL] 02/04/19 11:03:56 +01:00 WARNING: Error returned from fetch: -108**

I have tried to loadScore with the method "Social.LoadScores" and "PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadScores", but i'm getting the same warning.

PS: when i use Social.ShowLeaderboardUI() it shows me the leaderboard.
but when i use PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowLeaderboardUI(LB_Stars.id) to show a specific leaderboard it gives me "hmm,something went wrong in play games"

```
public void LoadLeaderboard()
{
    LB_Stars.LoadScores(ok =>
    {
        if (ok)
        {
            LoadUsersAndDisplay(LB_Stars);

        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Error retrieving STARS leaderboard");
        }
    });

}

internal void LoadUsersAndDisplay(ILeaderboard lbStar)
{

    Debug.Log("gonna load user and display them");

    List<string> userIds = new List<string>();

    foreach (IScore score in lbStar.scores)
    {
        userIds.Add(score.userID);
    }

    Social.LoadUsers(userIds.ToArray(), (users) =>
    {
        string status = "Leaderboard loading: " + lbStar.title + " count = " +
            lbStar.scores.Length;
        foreach (IScore score in lbStar.scores)
        {
            IUserProfile user = FindUser(users, score.userID);

            if (user != null)
            {

                UserLeaderboardClone = Instantiate(UserLeaderboardPrefab);
                UserLeaderboardClone.name = score.rank.ToString();

                LeaderboardUserScript lbUser = UserLeaderboardClone.GetComponent<LeaderboardUserScript>();
                lbUser.transform.SetParent(LBScrollview.content.transform, false);

                FillUserInfo(lbUser, user, score);

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you show a more detailed error than mentioned above so that the community could check?

Comment: i've figured it out, just removed the old google play game configuration, and started all over, everything is working just fine now !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i've figured it out, based on a comment on github https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/2045#issuecomment-350335234

Answer (score 0):

After spending a couple of hours on this, my problem turned out to be my game was using leaderboard ids from another app.
So it failed with this "unauthorized error", however the exact cause was not given.

The reason why it happened was because the play games configuration in unity was caching old values. When you open it - it has the correct ids, however in the generated GPGSids.cs file - wrong ids are present.

The solution was simply to regenerate that by re-saving the configuration.